# How to perform async tasks during shutdown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

I'm trying to create an async connection pool that keeps reference count for connections (multiple consumers can use one connection in parallel) and shuts down inactive ones after a timeout. I'm struggling to correctly implement shutdown logic: `cleanup_all` is called when the event loop is already shut down so I can't correctly call and await disconnect methods that return Futures. Is there a way to detect shutdown earlier and do clean up while the event loop is still active? I'm currently testing shutting down with keyboard interrupt but it should work in other modes too.

```
class ClientPool:

    class PoolItem:
        def __init__(self, client: Client):
            self.client = client
            self.last_used = 0.
            self.counter = 0

    clients: dict[int, PoolItem] = {}
    
    def __init__(self, max_idle_time=1*60):
        self.max_idle_time = max_idle_time
        atexit.register(self.cleanup_all)

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def acquire(self):
        item = await self.get_item()
        item.counter += 1
        try:
            yield item.client
        finally:
            item.counter -= 1
            item.last_used = time.monotonic()

    async def get_item(self) -> PoolItem:
        client = ...
        if client.id not in self.clients:
            await client.connect()
            self.clients[client.id] = self.PoolItem(c)
        return self.clients[client.id]

    async def dispose_item(self, item: PoolItem):
        del self.clients[item.client.id]
        await item.client.disconnect()

    def cleanup_all(self):
        tasks = [item.client.disconnect() for item in list(self.clients.values())]
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))

    async def cleanup(self):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(self.max_idle_time)
            try:
                t = time.monotonic()
                for client in list(self.clients.values()):
                    if client.counter == 0 and t - client.last_used > self.max_idle_time:
                        await self.dispose_item(client)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception(e)
```

Comment: I am not sure that I am on topic here, but you might want to have a look at the `signal` and `atexit` modules (native).

Comment: @Itération122442 I'm already using `atexit` and looks like it is triggering too late. `signal` might be a better way but I keep failing to implement it correctly.